# Unable to set Tool Tip content in style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I tried to set the Tooltip content property in style. But Tooltip text is displayed as System.Windows.Style. Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong?

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="149,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="29" Width="121">
        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="ToolTip Test"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
    </TextBlock>
```

[image: Image Reference]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you choose to do that? To have a default ToolTip value? But than why are you setting in on a TextBox and not globally?

Comment: I just want to show tooltip based on some conditions. To make my question simple I added up the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign a `ToolTip` to the `TextBox.ToolTip` property and then assign the `Style` to `ToolTip.Style`:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="TextBlock">
  <TextBlock.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip>
      <ToolTip.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
          <Setter Property="Content" Value="ToolTip Test" />
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Style>
      </ToolTip.Style>
    </ToolTip>
  </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

When setting `FrameworkElement.ToolTip` directly, the object is wrapped implicitly into a `ToolTip`. Since `Style` isn't a `FrameworkElement` and cannot be rendered, the `ContentControl` (`ToolTip`) invokes `object.ToString` on the content (the `Style` in your case) which returns the fully qualified type name as `string` by default.

Comment: Thanks, @BionicCode. For pointing out the problem and for the detailed explanation.